# xsd.exe gives errors when creating class with shcemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task.xsd

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I copied the a schema  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-schema but cannot create a class from it.

xsd complains:

> Schema validation warning: The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be `<schema>` and its namespace should be `'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'`. Line 2, position 2.
>   Error: Schema d:\scriptingutilities\task.xsd could not be validated.us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-schema**

I have tried making XMLSchema the default namespace (xmlns)and removing all of the xs: prefixes.  I get a different message:  **No top complex top level element**

Here are the first 61 lines of the schema:  (Entire file can be found at the above link)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema
targetNamespace="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"
xmlns:xs="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"
xmlns:td="https://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="Task" type="taskType">

    <xs:key name="PrincipalKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="td:Principals/td:Principal" />
        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
    </xs:key>
<!-- Principal id in Context attribute should match an id of
         some principal in Principals section. -->
    <xs:keyref name="ContextKeyRef" refer="PrincipalKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="td:Actions" />
        <xs:field xpath="@Context" />
    </xs:keyref>

    <!-- All ids must be unique -->
    <xs:unique name="UniqueId">
        <xs:selector xpath="td:Principals/td:Principal|td:Triggers/td:BootTrigger|td:Triggers/td:RegistrationTrigger|td:Triggers/td:IdleTrigger|td:Triggers/td:TimeTrigger|td:Triggers/td:EventTrigger|td:Triggers/td:LogonTrigger|td:Triggers/td:SessionStateChangeTrigger|td:Triggers/td:CalendarTrigger|td:Actions/td:Exec|td:Actions/td:ComHandler|td:Actions/td:SendEmail" />
        <xs:field xpath="@id" />
    </xs:unique>

</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="pathType">
    <xs:restriction base="nonEmptyString">
        <xs:maxLength value="260"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="versionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d+(\.\d+){1,3}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- Task -->

<xs:complexType name="taskType">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="RegistrationInfo" type="registrationInfoType" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Triggers"         type="triggersType"         minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Settings"         type="settingsType"         minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Data"             type="dataType"             minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Principals"       type="principalsType"       minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="Actions"          type="actionsType" />
    </xs:all>
    <xs:attribute name="version" use="optional" fixed="1.3" type="versionType" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: removing xs: wouldn't be the way to go. What is your toplevel tag ? Try posting the first line or two.

Comment: On lines 3 to 6 change From : https  To : http

Comment: Thanks, jdweng.  That worked.  I never would have thought of that.

Comment: @jdweng - that should be an answer. Good spot! :-)